# How to filter SQL result-set based on aliased column that uses STUFF FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql

I have a column that uses an alias in my SQL query. The results of the aliased column are comma-separated lists of languages spoken by the teacher.

```
SELECT 
    Teacher.LastName, 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + COALESCE((TeacherLanguage.LanguageName), '')
           FROM TeacherLanguage 
           INNER JOIN TeacherLanguageRel ON Teacher.TeacherId = TeacherLanguage.TeacherId
                  AND TeacherLanguage.LanguageId = TeacherLanguageRel.LanguageId 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS 'Languages' 
FROM 
    Teacher
```

Is there a way to filter the results using the values in the Languages column? Attaching a WHERE operator to the end of the query doesn't appear to work.

For example

```
WHERE Languages LIKE '%spanish%'
```

results in an error:

> Invalid column name 'Languages'.

Comment: You can't reference a column by its alias in the `WHERE`. Though I would recommend an `EXISTS` in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? I'd expect an error already at `AS 'Languages'`.

Comment: Also, only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. MySQL and SQL Server are *completely* different products.

Comment: You can wrap your statement as-is in an outer select, although filtering with a `where exists()` would be more performant.

Comment: WHERE EXISTS turned out to be exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do as you intend with your existing query as the `where` clause is evaluated *before* the `Languages` alias is defined.

You could do what you intend by turning your existing query into a *derived table* by wrapping in an outer select,

```
select * from (
  <your existing query>
)t
where Languages like '%spanish%'
```

However that will mean you are reading rows you don't want, which you could just filter out in your current query. I believe the following should work - untested of course.

```
select t.LastName, Stuff((
        select distinct ', ' + Coalesce((TeacherLanguage.LanguageName), '')
        from TeacherLanguage tl
        join TeacherLanguageRel tlr on tlr.LanguageId=tl.LanguageId
        where tl.TeacherId=t.TeacherId
            and tl.language like '%spanish%'
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') as Languages
from Teacher t
```

Note I've used *column aliases* in your query, and quotes should be reserved for string literals, not column aliases - `Languages` is not a reserved word so is fine as-is. This also of course assumes SQL Server.

Additionally since SQL Server 2017, `for XML path` is obsolete and can be replaced with `string_agg`.